# Need to call a JavaScript function and a code behind function at the same time when a user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe, onclick

I am working in a project that has C# code behind and a JavaScript file attached to the aspx.

I need to call a function in the JavaScript file and call a function from the code behind, all at the same time when the user clicks a button.

Essentially the JavaScript function is telling a service to save this form while the C# function is going to the next page.

I tried using onclick and onserverclick attributes for the button but it would only do one or the other (depending on if the on lock attribute returned true or false)

I also tried onbeforeunload and onsubmit to call the JavaScript function separately and it didn’t seem to work as nothing happened after the windows.postmessage call. (May be related to an iframe issue that I don’t know much about)

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Grumpy96 Have you tried onClick for server-side execution and onClientClick for javascript function?
However, the javascript function will trigger first and then server-side function.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this as it made more sense to me. Unfortunately similar results: only one of the two functions would be called

Comment: @Grumpy96 My c2 cents again to give a try to add button.Attributes.Addr("onClick", "javascriptfunction()") on page load and onClick for server-side function. If this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger javascript with `OnClientClick="functionName();"`

or you can trigger your postback from the jquery like below.

```
        $("buttonSelector").click(function{
           //Do your service call
          $("anotherSelector").trigger('click');
        })
```